# Mutating columns of a data frame based on a predicate function (dplyr::mutate_if)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I would like to use dplyr's `mutate_if()` function to convert list-columns to data-frame-columns, but run into a puzzling error when I try to do so. I am using dplyr 0.5.0, purrr 0.2.2, R 3.3.0.

The basic setup looks like this: I have a data frame `d`, some of whose columns are lists:

```
d <- dplyr::data_frame(
  A = list(
    list(list(x = "a", y = 1), list(x = "b", y = 2)),
    list(list(x = "c", y = 3), list(x = "d", y = 4))
  ),
  B = LETTERS[1:2]
)
```

I would like to convert the column of lists (in this case, `d$A`) to a column of data frames using the following function:

```
tblfy <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    purrr::transpose() %>%
    purrr::simplify_all() %>%
    dplyr::as_data_frame()
}
```

That is, I would like the list-column `d$A` to be replaced by the list `lapply(d$A, tblfy)`, which is

```
[[1]]
#  A tibble: 2 x 2
      x     y
  <chr> <dbl>
1     a     1
2     b     2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x     y
  <chr> <dbl>
1     c     3
2     d     4
```

Of course, in this simple case, I could just do a simple reassignment. The point, however, is that I would like to do this programmatically, ideally with dplyr, in a generally applicable way that could deal with any number of list-columns.

Here's where I stumble: When I try to convert the list-columns to data-frame-columns using the following application

```
d %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.list, funs(tblfy))
```

I get an error message that I don't know how to interpret:

```
Error: Each variable must be named.
Problem variables: 1, 2
```

*Why does `mutate_if()` fail? How can I properly apply it to get the desired result?*

**Remark**

A commenter has pointed out that the function `tblfy()` should be vectorized. That is a reasonable suggestion. But — unless I have vectorized incorrectly — that does not seem to get at the root of the problem. Plugging in a vectorized version of `tblfy()`,

```
tblfy_vec <- Vectorize(tblfy)
```

into `mutate_if()` fails with the error

```
Error: wrong result size (4), expected 2 or 1
```

**Update**

After gaining some experience with purrr, I now find the following approach natural, if somewhat long-winded:

```
d %>%
  map_if(is.list, ~ map(., ~ map_df(., identity))) %>%
  as_data_frame()
```

This is more or less identical to @alistaire's solution, below, but uses `map_if()`, resp. `map()`, in place of `mutate_if()`, resp. `Vectorize()`.

Comment: So what exactly is the expected output? You want to change A from a list of lists to a list of tibbles?

Comment: Your function is not vectorized, it only accepts one list. Look at `tblfy(d$A)`. There's an error because there are two lists in `d$A`. You are not comparing apples to apples. In your `lapply(d$A, tblfy)` you are giving your function one list at a time, that's why it works. `tblfy(d$A[[1]])` and `tblfy(d$A[[2]])`. In your dplyr function you are supplying two lists. Change `tblfy` to accept more than one list, or change the dplyr call. Or as MrFlick asks, think more broadly about what you're building.

Comment: @MrFlick I have edited the question to make the desired output explicit. Is it clear now?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Good point. I had already tried vectorizing but it still failed. See the edited question. Presumably I am vectorizing incorrectly. But how? Oddly, when I apply `tblfy_vec()` directly to `d$A`, I get a list of 4, which doesn't jive at all with my understanding that vectorizing creates a function that operates on a list (or vector) component-wise.

Comment: Try to insert an apply function. Either Map or lapply

Comment: `tblfy` doesn't function on the sample dataset for me. The problem is you really need to evaluate rowwise (or vectorize), and deal with the errors the original throws while not in a function. What _does_ work for me, if you can work it into a function: `d %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(A = A %>% map_df(identity) %>% list()) %>% tidyr::unnest()` You could vectorize to avoid `rowwise`, i.e. `d %>% mutate(A = Vectorize(function(x) x %>% map_df(identity) %>% list())(A)) %>% tidyr::unnest()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original `tblfy` function errors out for me (even when its elements are chained directly), so let's rebuild it a bit, adding vectorization as well, which lets us avoid an otherwise-necessary prior `rowwise()` call:

```
tblfy <- Vectorize(function(x){x %>% purrr::map_df(identity) %>% list()})
```

Now we can use `mutate_if` nicely:

```
d %>% mutate_if(purrr::is_list, tblfy)
## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
## 
##                A     B
##           <list> <chr>
## 1 <tbl_df [2,2]>     A
## 2 <tbl_df [2,2]>     B
```

...and if we unnest to see what's there,

```
d %>% mutate_if(purrr::is_list, tblfy) %>% tidyr::unnest()
## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## 
##       B     x     y
##   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
## 1     A     a     1
## 2     A     b     2
## 3     B     c     3
## 4     B     d     4
```

A couple notes:

- `map_df(identity)` seems to be more efficient at building a tibble than any of the alternative formulations. I know the `identity` call seems unnecessary, but most everything else breaks.
- I'm not sure how widely useful `tblfy` will be, as it's somewhat dependent on the structure of the lists in the list column, which can vary enormously. If you have a lot with a similar structure, I suppose it's useful, though.
- There may be a way to do this with `pmap` instead of `Vectorize`, but I can't get it to work with some cursory tries.

Comment: Thanks, that does it! Your version of `tblfy()` using `map_df()` is more concise than mine. Hadn't thought of doing it like that. In fact, looking at the source code for `map_df()` explains why your solution works, and particularly, why `list()` is necessary (which had puzzled me initially): because `map_df` is actually `map` followed by `bind_rows`, leaving out `list()` would result in a data frame of dimension 4 x 2.

Answer (score 7):

In-place conversion without any copying:

```
library(data.table)

for (col in d) if (is.list(col)) lapply(col, setDF)

d
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#                A B
#1 <S3:data.frame> A
#2 <S3:data.frame> B
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question about `mutate_if`, but a very nice alternative solution to the basic problem. data.table is new to me. Thanks!